# Can you get notifications of a computer not being used in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, nsnotification

I'm looking for a (likely) `NSNotification` which signals when a computer *hasn't been used in x amount of time*. Or it would be acceptable to have a notification that tells you every 1 or two minutes if it has been inactive since the last time.

It doesn't have to be a `NSNotification`, I just guessed based on other notifications that this would be how they were distributed.

Bonus points, anything special needed to pause NSTimers using this information?

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather broad, by computer I assume you mean the same computer the application is running on. If you are talking about another computer then the issue is more complex as one case of not beeing used for another computer is that it is turned off and then no notification can be sent. Thus if you are looking for a solution for any computer you need to implement some form of ping/heartbeat functionality.

If you mean on the same computer you still need to define what not beeing used means. No mouse or keyboard activity perhaps. But what about a user listening to music or watching youtube - is that in use or not?

In any case I think you cannot hope for a system message when it is not in use. I think you need to track the absence of messages that prove it is in use. One very heavy-handed appoach would be to trap all mouse and keyboard action and check how long ago you got the last such activity. This could be used as an indication of no activity.

For example the class method on NSEvent `+ (id)addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: NSEventMask)mask handler:(void (^)(NSEvent*))block` could be something to look into - but be prepared to handle a lot of events I suspect.

Comment: Not a bad idea, though there are numerous NSNotifications for almost everything I still suspect there is a system idle notification. :-) Thank you!